# How to get the value of datepicker in semantic ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, semantic-ui

I used [semantic ui calendar](https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar) , after pick a date with datepicker in javascript function I need to get the new value, but this calendar did not set the value, this is my html:

```
<div class="calendar datepicker">
        <i class="calendar icon"></i>
        <input type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

And in script file:

```
$('.datepicker').each(function (i, e) {
        $(e).calendar({
            formatter: {
                date: function (date, settings) {
                    return Globalize.formatDate(date, { date: 'full' });
                }
            }
        });
```

I need something like this:

```
$('.calendar input').chabge(function () {
                var newValue = $(this).val();
            });
```

Does any one have any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to run a callback when the user changes the date or programmatically change the date and then set the new date on the datepicker?

Comment: @Justin I need callback and I need a new value but I don't want to set the new date.

Answer (score 6):

To get the new date value,the following script can be used:

```
$('.ui.calendar').calendar({
  onChange: function (date, text) {
     var newValue = text;
  },
});
```

Please check the link :[jsfiddle.net/dj14/a29swpdk/](https://jsfiddle.net/dj14/a29swpdk/)